# Ubuntu 22.04 closing all applications automatically and nothing is reopening

Tags: bash, 22.04, google-chrome, snap, snap-store

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 on a HP Omen 16, ryzen 7, 16 gb RAM, 1 tb SSD.
My OS suddenly started having a problem, practically overnight (it was working just fine the previous night).
After using my laptop for roughly 30-40 mins, automatically all windows are closing by itself of every running application (Even if I'm running just one page of chrome) and then I can't reopen any application(chrome, mozilla, VLC player, anything!) or any saved file ( .mp4, .txt). Even the downloads folder won't open. If I try to run any command on the terminal, for eg sudo apt update, I get an error like bash: path/to/sudo : Input/Output error. The only new thing I did was update snapd that morning
I even uninstalled and deleted the dual boot and did a fresh installation, the problem persists. Please help!

Comment: You probably have a hardware/overheating/ventilation problem, leading to failures